# Access the Facebook Ads API without being an Ad Account Admin

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api

Is it possible to make calls to the Facebook Ads API without being an Ad Account Admin?  I have been using the Graph API Explorer to test the Ads API calls.  If the user is an Ad Account Advertiser or an Ad Account Analyst, he receives an 'OAuthException: (#10) You do not have sufficient permissions to perform this action' error.

Answer (score 2):

No, if you only have access to the Development access level of the API you can only access the API on behalf of users who are admins of both the app and of the ad account you want to access -

This is documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/access

To access ads on behalf of other users or access accounts for users who aren't admins of the account you need to get your app approved for the Basic or Standard access level